# Laravel 5 - View [home] not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I ran `composer update` and now I'm running into an issue. I'm getting this error when I'm trying to load my home view:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [home] not found.
```

Yes, files exists in my directory (resources/views, etc.). Name is `home.blade.php`.

My controller:

```
<?php namespace Hulahoop\Http\Controllers;

use Hulahoop\Http\Requests;
use Hulahoop\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

This was working fine and it's very basic function. What happened? Running on local homestead FYI.

**UPDATE:** When I run `php artisan serve`, I can view the home page view fine (i.e. on http://localhost:8000). But on homestead, no dice. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of laravel 5? This was a bug people were experiencing a few months ago. Also what happens if you change your namespace to App?

Comment: Def latest version. Just got it last week. I was able to change the namespace to App. But got an error in 'AppServiceProvider', which looks like it had my previous namespace still. i.e. storage/framework/config.php and `storage/framework/services.json.php`. I changed all instances to App. Still same error...

Comment: 3 things, laravel 5 is now at 5.0.1, make sure you have that version. `composer update` will ensure this. `composer dump-autoload` should fix namespace change issues. And finally make sure that your homestead VM has write access to the storage folder and all of it's sub folders.

Comment: Did all of that. Also checked, folder have read&write...agh.

Comment: It's weird actually. I installed a new larval project via composer, called `test`. Pointed to that folder in the `homestead.yam` file, but it's still giving me the same error - for the other project...what...the

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem.

Comment: You and me both - or rather can't figure out what it is anyways. :p

Comment: You can't replicate your own problem?

Comment: So if I change the mapped domain in the homestead.yam file to something else (i.e. http://test.app), new project will run. Is there some cache I don't know about for that previous domain that the problematic project was running on? Mac OS user here, if that helps.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There seem to be a problem with vagrant and `php artisan config:cache`.
If you run `php artisan config:clear` and then try to open the page - you should see it working fine - just make sure you don't cache it via artisan.

Comment: Ty @seb! This really helped me when migrating from one env to another

Comment: No problem @Maky - glad I could help.

Comment: Here's the explanation for this answer:
The reason is that the `config:cache` command sets all of the paths in the config files to be the paths on whichever machine the command was run. If you run artisan on the *host* machine and use `php artisan serve` on the *host* machine as well, then everything will work because the paths will be correct. However, those paths will not be the correct ones for inside the virtual machine so Laravel won't know where to find anything.

Comment: And the money answer is here folks

Comment: If you have copied the project from local to somewhere, be SURE to rename/remove config.php to config.php_ from your /bootstrap/cache directory. That was the trick for me!

Comment: Worked great! I am running Homestead on Windows 10, and started getting this error after renaming the repo. Running this command fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ `vendor/config.php` ] it's hard-coded for local development.

Comment: i am unable to run `php artisan config:clear` command in my production server and by editing paths in `vendor/config.php ` file i solved my problem. It may be not the direct solution but we can use it. @lhab Shoully your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give executable permission for the view folder 755