# Laravel: Error InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, migration, hosting

I' upload the project from localhost to my dedicated server and after so many problems, finally some pages works domain.com | domain.com/home | domain.com/allsites etc..

But now, the routes "domain.com/site/create" 
"domain.com/site/ID/manage", "domain.com/site/ID/edit" not found, i get this error, why?

> **InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [Site.create] not found.**
>
> in FileViewFinder.php line 137 at
>   FileViewFinder->findInPaths('Site.create',
>   array('/....../resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79 at
>   FileViewFinder->find('Site.create') in Factory.php line 151

I try artisan comands: cache:clear, route:clear, config:clear, config:cache and nothings works, i don't know where is the problem!

**On localhost it works perfectly**

Comment: Did you try `php artisan config:clear | cache`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your local OS is different from your production server OS you might be running into a case-sensitive issue and the file is not being found. make sure your files names are EXACTLY the same, case and all. This can happen especially if one environment is Mac and the other is Linux.

If the issue is not fixed, please go through the following link. It may help you

[Laravel 5 - View [home] not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578012/laravel-5-view-home-not-found)

[Laravel 5.1 View not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802687/laravel-5-1-view-not-found)

[Laravel 5 InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [.admin] not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262069/laravel-5-invalidargumentexception-in-fileviewfinder-php-line-137-view-admin)

Comment: Oh my god! Is that! "sites -> Sites", my OS-> Windows, Server OS-> Centos.  
Thank you! 

Thank you!  5 HOURS FOR THIS! 6am on my country, i go to bed quiet

Answer (score 15):

also multiple times its found that config cache being problem. Use following commands to finetune them.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Also, assigning 777 permission to bootstrap and storage worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue but cause was different. For me the problem  was permissions on `errors` folder. In particular the folder was not executable.

To resolve on linux:

```
$ chmod +x ../views/errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these commands:

`php artisan dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

**check you passed argument are in database fields or not!**

```
 $mailData = array(
                    'type' => 'email_subscription',
                    'user_mail' => $obj->email_id
                );
                
                Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send(new SendMail($mailData));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I write the Controller's name with a Caps letter. `Route::**C**ontroller(ProductsController::class)->group(function(){ Route::get('/','index')->name('home'); });`  I just update name as `Route::controller(ProductsController::class)->group(function(){ Route::get('/','index')->name('home'); });`  and now it works great.