# Is there any problem with naming my laravel project as crm

Tags: laravel

I try to create a laravel project named **crm** and got this error.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Project directory crm/ is not empty

I am using windows system. I have tried to name it in capital letters but got the same error

Comment: Laravel: Error InvalidArgumentException
 this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261746/laravel-error-invalidargumentexception

Comment: Check your folder 'crm', I should be totally empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its because the **path** which you are trying to create the laravel application

**already has the same folder that is not empty**

So If You need to create a laravel app by overwriting it

Try

```
laravel new crm --force
```

So `--force` will **Forces install even if the directory already exists**

Comment: can I do it using composer.   when i tried 'composer create-project laravel/laravel crm --force'     I am getting   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--force" option does not exist.

Comment: yes its is because the --force option will be available in laravel installer  https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L31  not the Composer